# A Conjunctive Adverb for Reverse

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, conjunctions

I'm looking for a simplistic manner to say

> To reverse a little, ...

or

> To go back to an earlier statement, ...

A single word conjunctive adverb would be best, similar to furthermore or however

Comment: Not a single word, but how about *backtracking somewhat*, or similar?

Comment: Could you provide more context? What exactly do you want to go on to day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To go back to an earlier statement, ...*

*A single word conjunctive adverb would be best, similar to furthermore or however.*

I don't think there is a single word (conjunctive adverb or anything else). In most contexts it would simply be "to go back / get back to where we were ..." or possibly "just to backtrack for a moment ...".

Answer (score 3):

**But to *resume* ...**

Here's a quote from Byron's *Don Juan*:

> For we all know that English people are
>   Fed upon beef—I won't say much of beer,
>   Because 't is liquor only, and being far
>   From this my subject, has no business here;
>   We know, too, they very fond of war,
>   A pleasure—like all pleasures—rather dear;
>   So were the Cretans—from which I infer
>   That beef and battles both were owing to her.
>
> **But to resume**. The languid Juan raised
>   His head upon his elbow, and he saw
>   A sight on which he had not lately gazed,
>   As all his latter meals had been quite raw,
>   Three or four things, for which the Lord he praised,
>   And, feeling still the famish'd vulture gnaw,
>   He fell upon whate'er was offer'd, like
>   A priest, a shark, an alderman, or pike.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to refer to something in the past but then continue on the present topic, you could use ***whilst***

> *Whilst it has been proven previously that X, I now refer to Y*

Answer (score 0):

Try "**continuing** from earlier", or "to continue from earlier."

> To go on after an interruption; resume

(TFD)